# Acessar dados de classes ja instanciadas

Tags: java, memória

Preciso acessar dados contidos em variaveis de classes ja instanciadas apartir de outras classes

```
User_Info info = new User_Info()
```

Acho que eu precisaria do endereço da memoria que esta a "info" certo?

```
public class User_Info {
    private int user_id;
    private String nickname;
    private Image profile_picture;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String country;
    private String gender;
    private String state;
    private Date date_nasc;

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }
    public Image getProfile_picture() {
        return profile_picture;
    }
    public void setProfile_picture(Image profile_picture) {
        this.profile_picture = profile_picture;
    }
    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }
    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }
    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public Date getDate_nasc() {
        return date_nasc;
    }
    public void setDate_nasc(Date date_nasc) {
        this.date_nasc = date_nasc;
    }
}
```

Comment: poste o código de User_Info.java

Comment: nao precisa do código...

Comment: Vc definitivamente não precisa do endereco de memoria de `info`. Pedi seu código para que seja possivel sabermos mais detalhes e de repente direcionar melhor a resposta para sua dúvida.

Comment: esta ai , eu instancio isso no começo do programa mas ao decorrer do tempo preciso alterar esses valores em outras classes , como vou fazer para acessar esses dados que ja estao na memoria?

Comment: @LucasBertollo vamos lá, se pode colocar o exemplo 1 no minimo das outras classes também, fazendo favor ?

Comment: @HarryPotter olha os comentários na minha resposta, ele quer uma referencia compartilhada de uma mesma classe em várias outras classes, ou talvez definir os atributos estaticamente.

Comment: Obrigado @Math, entendi vamos ver o desenrolar rs

Comment: @Math ISSO.. poderia me falar mais sobre essa referencia compartilhada?

Comment: @Math ele não quer singleton?

Comment: @HarryPotter também, são 3 opçoes

Comment: @Math gostaria de saber as 3 ahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando outra suposta classe chamada UsandoUserInfo.java, que está no mesmo pacote da sua classe User_Info, faça:

```
public class UsandoUserInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User_Info info = new User_Info();
        info.setUser_id(44); //definiu o valor da variável user_id como sendo 44
        System.out.println(info.getUser_id()); //pegou o valor e imprimiu 44 no seu console
    }
}
```

Pronto, você usou o get e o set da sua class User_Info para definir e pegar o valor de `user_id`

Entretanto, se você deseja alterar um mesmo atributo da sua classe User_Info a partir de outra classe você possui algumas alternativas, vejamos:

### 1) Compartilhar a referência armazenada pela variável de referência `info` com suas outras classes

Você pode criar uma referência e ao chamar outras classes você passa essa referência para elas, exemplo:

**UsandoUserInfo.java**

```
public class UsandoUserInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User_Info info = new User_Info();
        info.setUser_id(44);
        System.out.println("Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo: " + info.getUser_id());

        UsandoUserInfo2 u2 = new UsandoUserInfo2(info);
        u2.atribuiUserId();
        System.out.println("Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo2: " + info.getUser_id());
    }
}
```

**UsandoUserInfo2.java**

```
public class UsandoUserInfo2 {
    private User_Info info;
    public UsandoUserInfo2(User_Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
    public void atribuiUserId(){
        info.setUser_id(55);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo: 44
>   Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo2: 55

### 2) Fazer sua classe User_Info um singleton

Provavelmente o mais correto e livre de bugs, aqui você faz uso do padrão de projeto Singleton, que é uma forma de garantir que nunca existirá mais do que uma instância da sua classe em uma mesma JVM.

Para aplicar esse padrão você precisa basicamente definir um construtor privado na sua classe User_Info e controlar seu acesso. Ou seja, só quem vai chamar esse construtor é a própria classe. Sendo assim você garante que só criará uma única instância dela, que será quando a variável de referência por nula, depois disso você retorna a variável já criada ao invés de criar uma nova.

Para disponibilizar essa referência criada pelo sua própria classe você deve fazer um método estático que a disponibilize.

Exemplo:

```
public class User_Info {
    private int user_id;
    private String nickname;
    private static User_Info info;

    private User_Info() {
    }

    public static User_Info getInstance() {
        if(info == null) {
            info = new User_Info();         
        }
        return info;
    }

    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }
}
```

**UsandoUserInfo.java**

```
public class UsandoUserInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User_Info info = User_Info.getInstance();
        info.setUser_id(44);
        System.out.println("Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo: " + info.getUser_id());

        UsandoUserInfo2 u2 = new UsandoUserInfo2();
        u2.atribuiUserId();
        System.out.println("Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo2: " + info.getUser_id());
    }
}
```

**UsandoUserInfo2.java**

```
public class UsandoUserInfo2 {
    private User_Info info;

    public UsandoUserInfo2() {
        info = User_Info.getInstance();
    }

    public void atribuiUserId(){
        info.setUser_id(55);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo: 44
>   Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo2: 55

### 3) Definir suas variáveis da classe User_Info como sendo `static`.

Definir como `static` é mais fácil entretanto acredito que seja a pior das opções, pois fere o princípio do encapsulamento. Como não sei para o quê você precisa, não custa mostra a possibildiade:

**User_Info.java**

```
public class User_Info {
    public static int user_id;
    public static String nickname;
}
```

**UsandoUserInfo.java**

```
public class UsandoUserInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User_Info.user_id = 44;
        System.out.println("Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo: " + User_Info.user_id);

        UsandoUserInfo2 u2 = new UsandoUserInfo2();
        u2.atribuiUserId();
        System.out.println("Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo2: " + User_Info.user_id);
    }
}
```

**UsandoUserInfo2.java**

```
public class UsandoUserInfo2 {
    public void atribuiUserId(){
        User_Info.user_id = 55;
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo: 44
>   Valor atribuido pelo UsandoUserInfo2: 55

Comment: ok.. agora tambem quero acessar da classe UsandoUserInfo2 como faz?

Comment: @LucasBertollo você quer acessar exatamente o valor que foi definido nessa classe? Por exemplo, o 44?

Comment: isso e alterar para 55 por exemplo , mas da classe UsandoUserInfo2

Comment: @LucasBertollo as 3 opções que consigo imaginar :)

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `getter` /  `setters` como por exemplo, em uma variável fictícia `minhaString` definida dentro da sua classe User_Info:

```
public class User_Info {

   private minhaString;

   public String getMinhaString(){
     return minhaString;
   }

   public void setMinhaString(String str){
      minhaString = str;
   }
}
```

E então para acessar:

```
User_Info info = new User_Info()
info.setMinhaString("uma String");
String s = info.getMinhaString();
//s terá o valor de "uma String"
```

Ou então defina a variável como `public`:

```
User_Info info = new User_Info()
info.minhaString = "uma String";
```

Comment: isso eu sei ahaha acho que ninguem esta me intendendo... ok legal.. vamos supor eu instanciei isso na Main agora preciso alterar esses dados a partir da classe AlteraDados como vou acessar?

Comment: Lucas, você tem que passar seu objeto `info` como referencia... simples assim, ex: `AlteraDados ad = new AlteraDados(info);` ou criando um metodo qualquer: `AlteraDados ad = new AlteraDados();  ad.alteraValor(info);` entendeu ?

Comment: nao teria como pegar o endereço da memoria que esta esse objeto? para poder usar de qualquer parte do programa? porque outras classes nao conseguiriam ver "info" certo?

Answer (score 0):

Sua classe **User_Info** certamente possui atributos e esses atributos estão encapsulados em *getters* e *setters*, correto?

Para acessar os dados dos atributos basta chamar os *getters*. Por exemplo:

```
User_Info info = new User_Info();
info.setCodigo(1); // atribuirá o número '1' ao atributo 'codigo', supondo que seja um atributo do tipo int/Integer
System.out.println(info.getCodigo()); // imprimirá no console o que estiver guardado no atributo 'codigo'
```

Comment: certo mas para acessar ela de outra classe?

Comment: Se User_Info for um atributo estático, você poderá acessar de outra classe sem problemas, basta invocar os getters. Você precisa detalhar melhor o que já fez até agora, o que pretende fazer, qual o propósito do sistema, qual o propósito do User_Info, onde ele será usado, para que, por que, quando, como, etc...